# Get video from Youtube-DL is not working properly

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get youtube video by using youtube_dl and everything is working fine except for the fact that I only get the audio.

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

link = "SOME_YOUTUBE_VIDEO" # as it was only a video

with YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    url = info['formats'][0]['url']
    title = info["title"]
    print(url, title)
```

Comment: How did you install `youtube-dl`?  It has to be updated regularly, and the package managers do not stay up to date.  It's best to use `pip` and update regularly.  Check here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl

Comment: Well, maybe format 0 is audio-only? Have you tried different values? You left out the video url, so it's impossible to try.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I'm currently on Windows and If i check the version I have the latest version of youtube-dl and even python is not complaining.

Comment: @Sören I have also tried with other formats (such as mp4), the problem is the same, apart from the fact that now I can barely see the screen layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9wBC3H4iH4"

with YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    for i, format in enumerate(info['formats']):
        print(f"[{i}] {format['format']}")
```

output:

```
[youtube] Y9wBC3H4iH4: Downloading webpage
[0] 249 - audio only (tiny)
[1] 250 - audio only (tiny)
[2] 251 - audio only (tiny)
[3] 140 - audio only (tiny)
[4] 160 - 256x144 (144p)
[5] 278 - 256x144 (144p)
[6] 242 - 426x240 (240p)
[7] 133 - 426x240 (240p)
[8] 243 - 640x360 (360p)
[9] 134 - 640x360 (360p)
[10] 244 - 854x480 (480p)
[11] 135 - 854x480 (480p)
[12] 247 - 1280x720 (720p)
[13] 136 - 1280x720 (720p)
[14] 248 - 1920x1080 (1080p)
[15] 137 - 1920x1080 (1080p)
[16] 18 - 640x360 (360p)
[17] 22 - 1280x720 (720p)
```

It literally says `audio only` for some of the formats! Select one of the non-audio-only formats, and you won't get audio only. Note that which formats are available very much depends on which video you're trying to download.

Comment: As I said in the comments, I have also tried with formats such as mp4, my problem is that the video is still unavailable for being reproduced.

Comment: That sounds like a second problem.

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question wrong

Comment: Well, yes. Your question was, why you only get audio files. I answered that. Now you want to know, why the video is 'unavailable'. Whatever that means. The only thing your code does with the url is print it. printing a url doesn't download it.

Comment: Als please note, that stackoverflow is one question per post. If you want to ask a second question (like: 'What do I have to do to download a url like this: [...]'), please create a new post.